# How to avoid re-rendering of child components whenever parent's state is updated

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

Home.js =======> Parent component

```
import React, { useState, useReducer, useRef, createContext } from "react";
import { User1, User2, User3 } from "./User";

export const UserContext = createContext(null);
export const TypeContext = createContext(null); 

const Home = () => {
  const [user, setUser] = useState("User");
  const [type, setType] = useState("Free");
  return (
    <>
      <input type="text" onChange={(event) => setUser(event.target.value)} />
      <br />
      <input type="text" onChange={(event) => setType(event.target.value)} />
      <UserContext.Provider value={{ user }}>
        <User1 />
        
      </UserContext.Provider>
      <TypeContext.Provider value={{ type}}>
        <User2 />
      </TypeContext.Provider>
    </>
  );
};

export default Home;
```

User.js =============> Child Component

```
import React, { useContext, useMemo } from "react";
import { UserContext, TypeContext } from "./Home";

export const User1 = () => {
  const { user } = useContext(UserContext);
  console.log("user1");
  return <h1>Username is {user}</h1>;
 };

export const User2 = () => {
  const { type } = useContext(TypeContext);
  console.log("user2");
  return <h1>Username is {type}</h1>;
};

export const User3 = React.memo((props) => {
  console.log("user3");
  return <h2>My Props {props.title}</h2>;
});
```

It re-renders User1 and User2 every time anything changes in user or type as the state of parent update. I want when I change user only User1 should update and when I update type only User2 should update

Comment: [This](https://blog.agney.dev/useMemo-inside-context/) should help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a [working codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/compassionate-wiles-g6m2rc?file=/src/Home.js) that I created to handle your issue.

#### Explanation

You should memoize the child components if you want to render them only there is a change. Since you are not passing the values as props, you should also `useMemo` the context provider values:

*Home.js*

```
import { useState, createContext, useCallback, useMemo } from "react";
import { User1, User2 } from "./User";

export const UserContext = createContext(null);
export const TypeContext = createContext(null);

export const Home = () => {
  const [user, setUser] = useState({ user: "User" });
  const [type, setType] = useState({ type: "Free" });

  const handleUserChange = (event) => setUser({ user: event.target.value });

  const handleTypeChange = (event) => setType({ type: event.target.value });

  return (
    <>
      <input type="text" onChange={handleUserChange} />
      <br />
      <input type="text" onChange={handleTypeChange} />
      <UserContext.Provider value={user}>
        <User1 />
      </UserContext.Provider>
      <TypeContext.Provider value={type}>
        <User2 />
      </TypeContext.Provider>
    </>
  );
};

export default Home;
```

*User.js*

```
import { useContext, memo } from "react";
import { UserContext, TypeContext } from "./Home";

export const User1 = memo(() => {
  const { user } = useContext(UserContext);
  console.log("user1");
  return <h1>Username is {user}</h1>;
});

export const User2 = memo(() => {
  const { type } = useContext(TypeContext);
  console.log("user2");
  return <h1>Username is {type}</h1>;
});
```

Comment: why is it necessary to memoize `userValue` and `typeValue`? Per official docs it should be enough to avoid renders by referencing component state: https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html#caveats

Comment: I updated your sandbox by removing the `useMemo`  for `userValue` and `typeValue` and it still avoided re-rendering of children when parent re-renders. Is that expected? Thanks for this example.

Comment: Interesting actually, when I try it without useMemo, I can see a log for both components. With useMemo, I only see the log of the component which is updated :O

Comment: Here, in mine you can change `user` and only `user1` will print in the console log: https://codesandbox.io/s/compassionate-wiles-g6m2rc?file=/src/Home.js

Comment: Ah my bad, I see your point. You are correct you don't need the useMemo's apparently :)

Comment: @SinanYaman did React 18 actually change this? I can't tell. https://reactjs.org/blog/2022/03/29/react-v18.html Are you saying automatic batching made this unnecessary?

Comment: I remember watching a Reactathon video and someone saying React 18 will use `useCallback` and `memo` by default. I didn't try it though. Edit: I tried and it doesn't seem to be the case :)

Answer (score 0):

Changes to the context value will rerender all of the consumers, because React simply does an `===` comparison on the updated values, and you're creating the object inline (so it's different each time). See https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html#caveats

The solution is to memoize the value you pass to the provider, or use something like Redux or Zustand.

Comment: But value is updating every time I enter the value in the respective textfield. that's why I am using useState.

Comment: Yes, so every time you type, you rerender the component, which recreates the object passed to the provider, making the value different each time, which in turn rerenders the consumers

Answer (score 0):

you can use `shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps, nextState)` for this method.
Use shouldComponentUpdate() to let React know if a component’s output is not affected by the current change in state or props. The default behavior is to re-render on every state change, and in the vast majority of cases you should rely on the default behavior read docs [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#shouldcomponentupdate).
As a suggestion try not to use this unless absolutely necessary, this can cause bugs or performance issues but its the only method I know that is there so hpefully it helps

Comment: there's any way I can achieve this in functional component

Comment: use react memo hooks, here is the documentation: https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactmemo